# Why does dependabot PR does not show any release notes nor commits?

Tags: github, dependabot, github-dependabot

we have a public gradle plugin, which we release new versions, eg:
https://github.com/europace/docker-publish-gradle-plugin/releases/tag/v2.0.4
https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/de.europace.docker-publish

After the release dependabot creates pull requests in several of our services as expected. But even though there are release notes the desciption of the pull requests is always empty. I would have at least expected some commit messages there.

[image]

Any idea why dependabot does not find those release notes?

Comment: Not a direct answer to you question (because I don't know much about this ecosystem, sorry), but I think the relevant dependabot source code is here: https://github.com/dependabot/dependabot-core/blob/main/gradle/lib/dependabot/gradle/metadata_finder.rb -- perhaps that might give you some clue as to what's missing from the project configuration, leaving dependabot unable to pick up the release changelog?